# Node failing on perfectly valid Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

In my node module i have the following:

```
var dir = name.replace(/(^|\/)[^/]+$/, "$1"),
```

When I run a js file requiring that module, I get the following:

```
D:\repos\webgl\node_modules\glsl-simulator\dist\index.js:17
            var dir = name.replace(/(^|/)[^/]+$/, "$1"),
                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
```

If I take the same Regex and run it in chrome is runs successfully:

```
"runtime/event".replace(/(^|\/)[^/]+$/, "$1")
"runtime/"
```

Comment: Try Escaping `^` in your regex, like this: `/(\^|\/)[\^/]+$/`

Comment: This is weird, probably you may work around it using `.replace(/(^|[\/])[^\/]+$/, "$1")` or `.replace(new RegExp("(^|/)[^/]+$"), "$1")`. The latter is more portable I believe.

Comment: That worked however I got some error somewhere else. I think there's something wrong with my module. Thanks for the help guys